# How to take a rounded screenshot image in iOS

Tags: ios, screenshot

How to take a rounded  screenshot image in iOS

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(screenRect.size.width, screenH), NO, scale);

CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[showView.layer renderInContext:ctx];
UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

[the original image saved to galaxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HE9VB.jpg)

[the image show in a view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbrnY.png)

please check these two images.when the image saved to the galaxy.there are four rounded black area around the image.this is excess.I'm using iOS 15+.Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You can update your code like this (swift):

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: toSnap.frame.width, height: toSnap.frame.height), true, 1.0)
            
guard let ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else {
                debugPrint("Something not worked...")
                return
            }
            
toSnap.layer.cornerRadius = 20
toSnap.layer.render(in: ctx)
toSnap.layer.cornerRadius = 0
            
let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
            
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```